# Apex "IN" expression not querying all matching records

Tags: apex

This Apex Class should grab the records where the recordtype is either A or B.
However it will always end up with a list of **only** A records.

If code is changed to grab only A records, it works. If changed to grab only B records, then it also works, but it doesn't seem to be able to get both of them.
Tried with **OR** and **IN** expressions.

What am I missing here?

```
public class ambassadorukrow {

    public String c { get; set; }
    private id caserecordtype;

    private id accountrecordtype;
    Transient Map<id,case> casemap = new map<id,case>();
    list<case> clist = new list<case>();
    list<case> clist1 = new list<case>();
    list<case> clist22 = new list<case>();
    set<id> caseset = new set<id>();

    public ambassadorukrow() {
        clist22.clear();
        casemap.clear();
        getreasons();
        system.debug(pickvalue+'pick===');
        for ( recordtype rt : [select id from recordtype where name IN('1893 Ambassador Request', 'WebAMB Request') and Sobjecttype =: 'Case' limit 1] ) {
            caserecordtype=rt.id;
        }

        for ( recordtype rt:[select id from recordtype where name=: 'CustomerUK' and Sobjecttype =: 'Account' limit 1] ) {
            accountrecordtype=rt.id;
        }

        Map<id,id> accmap=new map<id,id>();
        set<id> accset=new set<id>();

        for ( case c : [select id,CaseNumber,AccountId,Account.Name,recordtypeid,account.lastname,
                            Origin,CreatedDate,status,Brochure__c,Brochure__r.name,Brochure__r.Brochure_Code__c 
                            from case where status='Send to Fulfilment - Accepted' And recordtypeid=:caserecordtype limit 50000]) {
            accset.add(c.accountid);
            if ( c.accountid != null ) {
                casemap.put(c.id,c);
            }
        }

        for ( account a : [select id,recordtypeid from account where recordtypeid=:accountrecordtype and id in:accset limit 50000] ) {
            accmap.put(a.id,a.recordtypeid);
        }

        for ( id cid : casemap.keyset() ) {
            if ( accmap.get(casemap.get(cid).AccountId) != null ) {
                caseset.add(cid);
            }
        }

        /*for(Case_Brochure_link__c c1:[select id,case__C,Brochure__c,case__r.CaseNumber,case__r.account.name,
        brochure__r.name,brochure__r.brochure_code__C from Case_Brochure_link__c 
        where case__c in :caseset and Pre_Order__c='False' and export_date__c=null order by case__r.caseNumber limit 50000])
        cblist.add(c1);*/
        /*if(cblist.size()>0)
        {
        for(case cc:[select id from case where id in: caseset])
        clist.add(cc);
        }*/
        for ( case cc : [select id,CaseNumber,AccountId,Account.Name,recordtypeid,Account.CRMid__c,Account.Firstname,Account.lastname,Account.Salutation,
                            Ambassador_Request_Reason__c, Account.PersonMobilePhone,Account.ShippingCountry__c,Account.ShippingPOBox__c,Account.ShippingPostalCode__c,
                            Account.ShippingRegion__c,Account.ShippingStreetNo__c,Account.Region__c,Account.ShippingBuilding__c,Account.Locality__c,
                            Account.ShippingStreet__c,Account.ShippingCity__c,Account.Mobile__c,Account.Fax,Account.Email__c,
                            Origin,CreatedDate from case where status='Send to Fulfilment - Accepted' And id in :caseset limit 50000] ) {
            clist22.add(cc);
        }
    }

    public list<Case> getcaserec1() {
        return clist22;
    }

    list<Case> cblist1=new list<Case>();
    public pagereference export() {
        cblist1.clear();
        for ( Case c21 : clist22 ) {
            //c21.export_date__C=system.today();
            c21.status='Close Accepted';
            cblist1.add(c21);
        }

        if ( cblist1.size() > 0 )
            update cblist1;

        //pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/ambassadorukrow?type=xls');
        pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/ambassadorukrow1');
        return p;
    }

    public string pickvalue{set;get;}
    list<case> casepicklist=new list<case>();
    list<case> casecloselist=new list<case>();

    public List<SelectOption> getreasons() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = case.Ambassador_Request_Reason__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None', 'None'));   
        options.add(new SelectOption('All', 'All'));  
        for ( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple ) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public void applyfilter() {
        casepicklist.clear();
        if ( pickvalue == 'All' ) {
            for ( case casepick : [select id,CaseNumber,AccountId,Account.Name,recordtypeid,Account.CRMid__c,Account.Firstname,Account.lastname,Account.Salutation,
                                    Ambassador_Request_Reason__c, Account.PersonMobilePhone,Account.ShippingCountry__c,Account.ShippingPOBox__c,Account.ShippingPostalCode__c,
                                    Account.ShippingRegion__c,Account.ShippingStreetNo__c,Account.Region__c,Account.ShippingBuilding__c,Account.Locality__c,
                                    Account.ShippingStreet__c,Account.ShippingCity__c,Account.Mobile__c,Account.Fax,Account.Email__c,
                                    Origin,CreatedDate from case where status='Send to Fulfilment - Accepted' And id in :caseset limit 50000] ) {
                casepicklist.add(casepick);
            }
        } else {
            for ( case casepick : [select id,CaseNumber,AccountId,Account.Name,recordtypeid,Account.CRMid__c,Account.Firstname,Account.lastname,Account.Salutation,
                                    Ambassador_Request_Reason__c, Account.PersonMobilePhone,Account.ShippingCountry__c,Account.ShippingPOBox__c,Account.ShippingPostalCode__c,
                                    Account.ShippingRegion__c,Account.ShippingStreetNo__c,Account.Region__c,Account.ShippingBuilding__c,Account.Locality__c,
                                    Account.ShippingStreet__c,Account.ShippingCity__c,Account.Mobile__c,Account.Fax,Account.Email__c,
                                    Origin,CreatedDate from case where status='Send to Fulfilment - Accepted' And id in :caseset and Ambassador_Request_Reason__c=:pickvalue limit 50000] ) {
                casepicklist.add(casepick);
            }
        }
        system.debug(casepicklist+'cp===');
    }

    public list<case> getfilterlist() {
        return casepicklist;
    }
    public pagereference exportpick() {
        casecloselist.clear();
        for ( Case c22 : casepicklist ) {
            //c21.export_date__C=system.today();
            c22.status='Close Accepted';
            casecloselist.add(c22);
        }

        if ( casecloselist.size() > 0 )
            update casecloselist;

        //pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/ambassadorukrow?type=xls');
        pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/ambassadorukrow1');
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple query in your code... May i know for which query you are talking about ?

Comment: Atheri - Have you tried putting ID's instead of names in  ( FirstRecordTypeID, SecondRecordTypeID)  ,   If it works with ID then you are missing something with your Names  - that could be Whitespace, Caps, Typo, etc.

Comment: It looks like you are limiting your caserecordtype record type search to only 1 record (limit 1). As soon as it finds a match, it would stop, wouldn't it? So, your for Case section where you reference the caserecordtype only has 1 value to search against.

Comment: Hi!

- Nilesh Mendhe - yes, I've tried with ID's too and the results are the same. 
- smckitrick - removing the LIMIT will only make 'WEBAmb Request' cases visible for some reason. 
- PrabhatKumar - the first one, where case status is 'Send to Fulfilment Accepted'.

So in it' s current state it will list the '1893 Ambassador Request' cases and with some changes to it, like removing LIMIT then only 'WEBAmb Request' cases are shown - but never both of them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you change your caseRecordType to List and the query.

```
set<id> caserecordtype =new set<id>();


    for(recordtype rt:[select id from recordtype where name IN('1893 Ambassador    Request', 'WebAMB Request') and Sobjecttype =: 'Case' limit 1]){
        caserecordtype.add(rt.id);
}
   //Then query like this

for(case c:[select id,CaseNumber,AccountId,Account.Name,recordtypeid,account.lastname,
Origin,CreatedDate,status,Brochure__c,Brochure__r.name,Brochure__r.Brochure_Code__c 
from case where status='Send to Fulfilment - Accepted' And recordtypeid IN: caserecordtype limit 50000]) 
{
accset.add(c.accountid);
if(c.accountid!=null)
casemap.put(c.id,c);
}
```

One more thing i noticed you have used for loop without curly braces for the caseRecordType which runs only one so you are adding only one record type there.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate on the for-loop missing curly brace? Are there any adjustments to that specific code I can do to display both record types?